# How to check which subclass is the event fired?

Tags: dart, dart-html

I know `event.type` in DOM. I can parse for example `mouseup`, `keydown`, `touchstart` and so on. But how can I check for the event subclass? Like `MouseEvent`, `AnimationEvent` or `ClipboardEvent`? Can I use the `event.type` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the class like

```dart
void myHandler(Event e) {
  if(e is MouseEvent) {
    print('Mouse');
  } else if(e is AnimationEvent) {
    print('Animation');
  } else if(e is KeyboardEvent) {
    print('Keyboard');
  }
}
```

Comment: looks easier, I'll test it

Comment: So `if(e is MouseEvent||e is TouchEvent||e is KeyboardEvent){...}` is better than `if(e.runtimeType.toString()=='MouseEvent'||e.runtimeType.toString()=='TouchEvent'||e.runtimeType.toString()=='KeyboardEvent'){...}`? To me, they seem to behave the same and to work great both...

Answer (score 1):

Since JavaScript is a [prototype-based language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) you can to do it a bit strangely using `Object.prototype.toString.call()` and then cleaning up the result a little, like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById("testEvent");

button.onclick = function(e) {
    console.log(
        Object.prototype.toString.call(e).replace(/^\[object ([^\]]*)\]/, "$1")
    );
}
```

This fiddle shows it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/SrmGJ/1/ working for me in FireFox. It should output `"MouseEvent"` in the fiddle, but if you hook it up to [some of the other events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events), you will see different results.

Another method would be to call `EventType.prototype.isPrototypeOf(e)` for each of the  types:

```
...
if (MouseEvent.prototype.isPrototypeOf(e)) { console.log("MouseEvent"); }
if (AnimationEvent.prototype.isPrototypeOf(e)) { console.log("AnimationEvent"); }
if (KeyboardEvent.prototype.isPrototypeOf(e)) { console.log("KeyboardEvent"); }
...
```

But that would look pretty nasty IMHO.

Comment: The fiddled solution looks great! Thank you

Comment: Ah, you didn't specify the language. Maybe in Dart you can just call `event.runtimeType.toString()` ?

Comment: Yeah, because first I meant to ask universally. Speciffically it depends on language used, but I think, that it isn't so much different. And it could help programmers at all.
And in both languages (JS and Dart) your solutions work perfectly, thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't use `.runtimeType` for anything else than debugging purposes because it is not reliable. `Any class can override its `runtimeType` getter and return whatever String it wants.